# URLs Added to ACF Repeater Field are not working

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, page-template

I have created a page using the "Advanced Custom Fields" Plugin and everything is working great except that when I add href url in the field text it doesn't show nicely on Front-end and break the layout: http://prntscr.com/qtihpj.

[image]

The field in question is the Repeater field. Does anyone know how to fix it? I appreciate the help!

Comment: It looks like there must be some CSS forcing the `<a>` tag to be `display:block` or something similar. Inspect the element with dev tools to find out where the styling is coming from.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks for the tip. Here is the page url: https://is.gd/zvaQnw if you can assist further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the wrapper around that text block is set to `display: flex;`.

You could override this by adding the following CSS...

```
.special-list .right-text {
    display: block;
}
```

You can add this in Admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS

You might want to add this and then test other pages that use this code to make sure it doesn't break anything else.

Comment: This worked well, thanks!